# How to disable strapi graphql playground on production mode

Tags: graphql, strapi, graphql-playground, graphql-config

I've added this snippet into `./config/plugins.js`

```
module.exports = {
  graphql: {
    enabled: true,
    config: {
      endpoint: "/graphql",
      shadowCRUD: true,
      playgroundAlways: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development",
      depthLimit: 50,
      amountLimit: 100,
      defaultLimit: 100,
      maxLimit: 100,
      apolloServer: {
        tracing: true,
      },
    },
  },
  ckeditor: true,
};
```

I also have changed `playgroundAlways` value like this:

```
    playgroundAlways:false
```

But I can see graphql playground in development and production mode.

How can I hide or disable graphql playground?

Answer (score 0):

How are the start app script defined?
Are you setting the NODE_ENV=production?

To double check set a breakpoint or console.log `process.env` variable to see what you are getting at the runtime.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32908006)